# Page load Function (js) is not working when Web page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to find out how to call my function that is inside a function that is started on page load to set darkmode.

If anyone could help me with this I would be very grateful.

Here is my js file:

```
(function() {
  var darkSwitch = document.getElementById("darkSwitch");
  if (darkSwitch) {
    initTheme();
    darkSwitch.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      resetTheme();
    });
    function initTheme() {
      var darkThemeSelected =
        localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") !== null &&
        localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") === "dark";
      darkSwitch.checked = darkThemeSelected;
      darkThemeSelected
        ? document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark")
        : document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme");
    }
    function resetTheme() {
      if (darkSwitch.checked) {
        document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
        localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark");
      } else {
        document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme");
        localStorage.removeItem("darkSwitch");
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

The js file comes from this GitHub:
https://github.com/coliff/dark-mode-switch

Comment: Not clear where the specific problem is or what errors are thrown in browser dev tools console. Note it is a really bad practice to declare functions in an `if()`

Comment: If you want to call `resetTheme` for example outside of the wrapper function, you should assign it on the window - `window.resetTheme = function() {...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you try when the page is load is in dark mode.
here is the solution of your problem.

**Here its Documentation :**

Here's [a link](https://codepen.io/henryegloff/pen/Eqwzeb)! This code  is from  [Codepen](https://codepen.io/).

**HTML:**

```
<script>
    // Include this script near the top of your html
    var app = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    if (localStorage.lightMode == "dark") {
        app.setAttribute("data-light-mode", "dark");
    }
</script>

<h1>
    Dark Mode Toggle
</h1>
<p>Uses localStorage to store and apply the set light mode when page is loaded</p>
<button onclick="toggle_light_mode()">
    Toggle Light Mode
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-top: 3em;
}

h1 {
    font-weight: normal;
}

button {
    padding: 1em;
    font-size: 1em;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
}

button:hover {
    opacity:.5;
}

body[data-light-mode="dark"] {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #eee;
}
body[data-light-mode="dark"] button {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

**JS**

```
    function toggle_light_mode() {

        var app = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];

        if (localStorage.lightMode == "dark") {
            localStorage.lightMode = "light";
            app.setAttribute("data-light-mode", "light");
        } else {
            localStorage.lightMode = "dark";
            app.setAttribute("data-light-mode", "dark");
        }
        console.log("lightMode = " + localStorage.lightMode);
    }
```